# SwiftUI: Keyboard gets dismissed after typing first character for TextField in navigation bar

Tags: ios, binding, keyboard, swiftui, textfield

I got a problem with a TextField in my SwiftUI app. I use it as a search bar in the navigation bar like that:

```
struct TextFieldInNavBar: View {
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    @Binding var test: String

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            EmptyView()
                .navigationBarItems(leading: TextField("Placeholder", text: self.$searchText))
        }
    }
}
```

Every time when I type a character the keyboard is getting dismissed. I figured out that the reason seems to be the `test` property with the @Binding property wrapper. If I remove it, everything works as desired.

Also this only happens when the TextFields is in the navigation bar, NOT in the body itself.

Comment: its working on Xcode 13.4.1, keyboard  didn't dismissed

Comment: Updated my Xcode to version 11.4.1, but it still dismisses the keyboard. The simulator is now running on iOS 13.4.1.

Comment: Consider solution [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61327558/12299030)... actually you posted earlier, so that one is duplicate, but I met that one first, so posted answer there...

Comment: @Asperi It looks good, but I actually not really can figure out how to use this for my own example. Could you please provide an example for that?

Comment: Post suggested by @Asperi completely solves the issue