# Why does a SwiftUI TextField inside a navigation bar only accept input one character at a time

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I want to allow the user to filter data in a long list to more easily find matching titles.

I have placed a TextView inside my navigation bar:

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Library"))
.navigationBarItems(trailing: TextField("search", text: $modelData.searchString)
```

I have an observable object which responds to changes in the search string:

```
class DataModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var modelData: [PDFSummary]
   @Published var searchString = "" {
            didSet {
                if searchString == "" {
                    modelData =  Realm.studyHallRealm.objects(PDFSummary.self).sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name })
                } else {
                    modelData =  Realm.studyHallRealm.objects(PDFSummary.self).sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name }).filter({ $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased()) })
                }
            }
        }
```

Everything works fine, except I have to tap on the field after entering each letter. For some reason the focus is taken away from the field after each letter is entered (unless I tap on a suggested autocorrect - the whole string is correctly added to the string at once)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in rebuilt `NavigationView` completely that result in dropped text field focus.

Here is working approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

The idea is to avoid rebuild `NavigationView` based on knowledge that SwiftUI engine updates *only* modified views, so using decomposition we make modifications local and transfer desired values only between subviews directly not affecting top `NavigationView`, as a result the last kept stand.

[image: demo]

```
class QueryModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var query: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // No QueryModel environment object here - 
    //                implicitly passed down. !!! MUST !!!

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ResultsView()
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Library"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: SearchItem())
        }
    }
}

struct ResultsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var qm: QueryModel // << injected here from top
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Search: \(qm.query)") // receive query string
        }
    }
}

struct SearchItem: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var qm: QueryModel // << injected here from top
    @State private var query = "" // updates only local view

    var body: some View {
        let text = Binding(get: { self.query }, set: {
            self.query = $0; self.qm.query = $0;       // transfer query string
        })
        return TextField("search", text: text)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(QueryModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need.  The list grows and shrinks as I type and hit delete. Thanks again for your help.